# TMux Scrollback Becomes Static

Tags: terminal, tmux

I have a kinda weird question. Sometimes in some of my long-lived tmux sessions I'll have a window where the history will get kinda "stuck"

So, to clarify, that's a (bash) shell, inside a pane, inside tmux, and that shell has been running for a while.

I have my scrollback set high and I use it all the time, so I know how to use it and how it works in tmux. But sometimes something will happen and I'll always get the same history when I scroll back no matter what I print.

So for example, I'll run something like `seq 1 100` and I'll only see the numbers 76 to 100 in the pane, but when I scroll up I don't see 75, I'll see the result of some git command I ran a while back. No matter what I run, when I scroll up it's that same output of that same git command, or whatever happens to have been up there when it broke.

I can exit the shell and re-open it, that works, but I'd rather not. I'm wondering if there's some kind of term control character or something, or broken curses code, or something that maybe didn't clean up properly in my terminal that would have left me in this in-between state where new lines are shown, but not added to the history? Any idea? I tried running `reset`, but it doesn't seem to have fixed it.

Does this make sense to anybody? I'd love to learn something new about how shells communicate with terminal emulators that makes this make sense.

Thanks!